# Autopopulate Column in 1 Excel Worksheet based on boxes ticked on another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build some worksheets that teams can fill in to show which capabilities are required by particular projects. The list of Capabilities is fixed. The project list will be populated by them.

The first worksheet has Projects down one side and Capabilities along the top. If a particular project (that they enter) contains a capability along the top, they must tick the corresponding cell where column and row cross.

In the second worksheet, I would like a list to pre populate based on choices of the first. For example, for each project i would like to have the capabilities (column headers of columns where ticks are in first sheet) listed.

Hopefully I have conveyed this clearly!

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could even give me a name for what I am trying to do so that I can focus even my own manual search on the internet!

Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a "Code for Me","Show me where to find the code" or "Teach me to code" site.  If you have problematic code then post it in your original post using edit and tell us where it is failing and we will help overcome the issue.

Comment: @scottCraner Thankyou. I did not mean to devalue the community. I am not asking for someone to do it for me, just to provide the correct terminology for what I am trying to do so that I can teach myself! But if that is not within the remit of the site I understand.

Comment: There is no magic word that can be searched to get what you want.  Break the steps down and google each step individually.  You may get lucky and the answers to one step may answer those of other steps at the same time.

Comment: It's difficult to make any suggestions (in general terms) as it's unclear how the second sheet would be laid out.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks! It would be the first column of another table. For example, A1 would be the first project entered, A2 would be the first capability selected, A3 the next one, and so on... Once all Capabilities of Project 1 listed - it would continue to Project 2 and so on...

Comment: @ScottCraner Thankyou Scott for your advice.

Comment: All in Column A ?

Comment: @timWilliams Yes. Just need it to be the first column of a new table...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

    Dim shtList, rw As Range, r As Long
    Dim rNum As Long, rngProj As Range, cNum As Long

    Set shtList = Sheets("Listing")

    'assume data starts in A1 and contains no blank rows/columns
    Set rngProj = Sheets("Projects").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    r = 2

    For rNum = 2 To rngProj.Rows.Count
        Set rw = rngProj.Rows(rNum)
        shtList.Cells(r, 1).Value = rw.Cells(1).Value 'project
        r = r + 1
        For cNum = 2 To rw.Columns.Count
            If rw.Cells(cNum).Value = "x" Then
                shtList.Cells(r, 1).Value = rngProj.Rows(1).Cells(cNum).Value
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next cNum
    Next rNum

End Sub
```